# error: invalid use of non-static member function in c++

Tags: c++

This is the code i wrote
i guess there is alot of space for improvement...

how ever as im still learning my main focus right now is just to get it working

ill try and optimize things here and there later on

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Movie
{

private:
std::string Name, MPAA;
public:

    int Terrible = 0, Bad = 0, Ok = 0, Good = 0, Great = 0, TotalRated = 0;

    Movie() 
{
    Name = "";
    MPAA = "";
    TotalRated = 0;
}

void addRating (int i); // decleration of rating function
double getAverage(void); // decleration of avg function
std::string accessName() {return(Name);} // accessor for Name
void mutateName(std::string aName);
std::string accessMPAA() { return MPAA;} // accessor for MPAA
void mutateMPAA(std::string aMPAA);
};

void Movie::mutateName(std::string aName) // mutator for Name
{
    Name = aName;
}

void Movie::mutateMPAA(std::string aMPAA) // mutator for MPAA
{
    MPAA = aMPAA;
}

void Movie::addRating(int i) // not the most elligant but it does the job, checks and adds rating. might try using an array
{
    if((i > 0) && (i < 6))
    {
    if(i == 1)
    {
        Terrible++;
        TotalRated++;
    }
    if(i == 2)
    {
        Bad++;
        TotalRated++;
    }
    if(i == 3)
    {
        Ok++;
        TotalRated++;
    }
    if(i == 4)
    {
        Good++;
        TotalRated++;
    }
    if(i == 5)
    {
        Great++;
        TotalRated++;
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "your input was Invalid" << endl; // outputs error for invalid submition
}
};

double Movie::getAverage() // gets avg rating (total score / total times rated)
{
return (Terrible + (Bad * 2) + (Ok * 3) + (Good * 4) + (Great * 5)) / TotalRated;
};

int main()
{
Movie MovieOne;
//Movie 1
MovieOne.mutateName("Action");
MovieOne.mutateMPAA("PG13");
//Viewer 1
MovieOne.addRating(5);
    //Viewer 2
MovieOne.addRating(3);
//Viewer 3
MovieOne.addRating(3);
//Viewer 4
MovieOne.addRating(2);
//Viewer 5
MovieOne.addRating(4);
std::cout << "Name " << MovieOne.accessName << " MPAA " << MovieOne.accessMPAA << " AVG Rating is " << MovieOne.getAverage << endl;
};
```

The error i get is only here in the cout line

things are a little unclear to me as im currently using a mac to code while im traveling.. i have never even uses a apple laptop before

i have read some articles that says something should be set to static

Comment: Think a little, how do you ***call*** a function, *any* function?

Comment: What is the error? If you mean a compiler error, please paste it. And if you can remove any code that isn't required to reproduce the code, it'd be much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis required for the function calls

```
std::cout << "Name " << MovieOne.accessName() 
          << " MPAA " << MovieOne.accessMPAA() 
          << " AVG Rating is " << MovieOne.getAverage() 
          << '\n';
```

Comment: i have not been studying as much as i should so i have some things due that i now have to complete in a short amount of time. thanks though dont know how i missed that